# SQL Server Management Studio - is a many to NONE relation possible?

Tags: sql-server

Is a many to *none* (not one) relation even possible, and if yes, how would I do it?

To give you a bit more to work with, the database consists of Bible texts. It consists of books containing chapters containing verses, all very simple. The problem is the search index. I need to create an index table with all words longer than two characters, each pointing to all the verses this word occurs in. But there is absolutely no need for the verses to point back at them. If they'd point back, I'd need a many to many relation, which I also currently don't know how to do, but there's really no need for that redundant data. It won't ever be used. All I need is the pointer from the word index to the appropriate verses. No return ticket required.

I could do this easily enough in a code first approach, but it is the expressed purpose of the exercise to get familiar with database first modelling, so I'm stuck with SQL Server Management Studio...

Comment: Add a table `WordVerses` with columns: `WordID` and `VerseID`? It is many-to-many, because each word can be used in many verses and each verse consists of many words. I don't see why it is not many-to-many.

Comment: Of course it can be many to many... it just seems like redundant data, because it will never need to link back from a verse to a search term. It doesn't harm the function if it's many to many, but would be more efficient if it were many to none. But that's mostly me comming from a school of programming where you were scholded for every wasted byte...

Comment: You are not wasting anything. As shown in the accepted answer, you **need both** `WordID` and `VerseID` columns in the `WordVerses` table. You may not need an extra `ID` in that table, because you should have a `UNIQUE` constraint on two columns `WordID` and `VerseID` there anyway. Which means it is a good idea to make `PRIMARY KEY` that consists of these two columns. As you are going to use `WordID` for searching, rather than `VerseID`, then you should put `WordID` first and `VerseID` second in the composite index. Also, add foreign keys to the schema and index on `VerseID` and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Verses(ID INT, Text NVARCHAR(200))
CREATE TABLE WordIndex(ID INT, Word NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

You may create third table

```
CREATE TABLE WordIndexVerses(ID INT, WordIndexID INT, VerseID INT)
```

where you link index word with different verses in which this word exists.

```
For example:
Verses(ID, Text)
1, 'My Lord'
2, 'My God'

WordIndex(ID, Word)
1, 'My'
2, 'Lord'
3, 'God'

WordIndexVerses(ID, WordIndexID, VerseID)
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 2, 1
4, 3, 2
```

Comment: Blyme, I didn't see the forrest because of all the trees! *facepalms* Thanks a lot!